# How to change database name for Joomla?

Tags: joomla

I am tranferring Joomla website from my local server to a live server.

I need to change the database name when I do so.

Can anyone tell me which file I need to change please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

configuration.php in the root of the joomla install, replace the line

```
var $db = 'old-database'
```

with:

```
var $db = 'new-database'
```

Comment: Also, be sure to change the hostname and password if necessary:

var $password = 'newpassword';
var $host = 'localhost';

Answer (score 2):

configuration.php in the root of the joomla install, replace the line

```
public $host = 'localhost';
public $user = 'root';
public $password = '';
public $db = 'Old_database_Name';
```

with

```
public $host = 'localhost';
public $user = 'Server_host_user_name';
public $password = 'Server_host_password';
public $db = 'New_database_name';
```

Answer (score 0):

log in to your c panel ..
your back end will open..

go to the file manager
you will find all the pages you have created..

find out configuration.php page

go to the online html editor or just download the file and open it from you html editor software such as notepad++ or dreamweaver or other

also check var $db and replace the old with new name..

hope this will help..

Thanks
Anil BIkram Thapa

Answer (score 0):

Just replace in the configuration file present in the root of joomla folder :

`public $db = 'old_database_name';`

with

`public $db = 'new_database_name';`

You can also change the database username and password from the same file.

Answer (score 0):

**you can see below parameter into configuration.php file which is at your root joomla site**

public $host = 'localhost';

public $user = 'root';

public $password = '';

public $db = 'database name';

with

public $host = 'localhost';

public $user = 'server username(which you create for database connection)';

public $password = 'server password (which you enter during user create)';

public $db = 'New_database_name';

**Note : you can change prefix of database also using $dbprefix**

Answer (score 0):

simple process:
1.open configuration.php

2.change all database value

```
public $host = 'localhost';
public $user = 'root';
public $password = '';
public $db = 'Old_database_Name';
```